# Lacking concept on editable html email

Tags: javascript, php

I have a button on a php created html page that on click a javascript function posts specific element values to another php page, does a mysql query, creates a html email and automatically sends it without user interaction.  Works great.

An additional step has now been requested to be able to view the email and potentially edit it before it is sent and I am lacking a concept of how to do it. Preferably without destroying the code I already have.

Maybe something like a message box....do you want to review email (yes/no) no continues sending the email and yes allows it to be edited.

Any thoughts or input would be great.

adding current code:

Page1.php

```
echo "<td>";
if ($x == "Y"){$sent1 = "Y"; $checkcolor1 = 'images/greencheck.jpg';} else {$sent1 = "N"; $checkcolor1 = 'images/redcheck.jpg';}
echo "<div id='stepA$a' title='$sent1$a' value='$mycode'><a id='$a' href='' class ='step1'><div id='stepB$a'><img src='$checkcolor1' title='Send Rental Agreement' border='0' height='24' width='24'></img></div></a></div>";
echo "</td>";
```

Javascript Function

```
    $(".step1").on("click", function () {
    var element = $(this);
    var I = element.attr("id");
    var id = $("#id" + I).val();
    var checkname1 =  $("#stepA" + I).attr("title");
    var code =  $("#stepA" + I).attr("value");
    $.post("page2.php", {
        id: id, checkname1: checkname1, code: code          
    },
    function (data) {
        var response = (data).split(";", 2);
        $("#stepA" + I).attr("title", (response[0]));   
        $("#stepB" + I).html(response[1]);
        $("#stepB" + I).hide();
        $("#stepB" + I).fadeIn(1500);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Page2.php

```
<?php
include('connection.php');

$mycode = $_POST['code']; 

if (empty($mycode)) {die("No Value");}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT code FROM code WHERE code = '$mycode'") or die ( mysql_error ());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

$id=$_POST['id'];
$checkname1=$_POST['checkname1'];
$rest = $checkname1 [0];

if ($rest == "Y"){

    $checkchange1 ="Y$id";
    $checkchange2 ="<img src='images/greencheck.jpg' title='Send Rental Agreement' border='0' height='24' width='24'></img>";
    echo $checkchange1.";".$checkchange2.";";   

} else {    

    $change="Y";
    $query = "UPDATE info SET invoice = '$change' WHERE id = $id";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ( mysql_error ());

$query = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE id = '$id'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ( mysql_error ());


if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {      

while(list($a,$b,$c,$d,$e) = mysql_fetch_row($result)) { 

$mail_body ='
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" width="174" height="70"></img><br />
<p><b>HTML Email body</b></p>';}

            $to = $e;                       

            $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
                       'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n" .
                       'From: Rental<hell@test.com>' . "\r\n" .
                       'Reply-To: hello@test.com' . "\r\n" .
                       'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();         
            $subject = 'Rental Agreement ' . $d . ', ' . $l . ' - ' . $m;

            mail($to, $subject, $mail_body, $headers);  


    $checkchange1 ="Y$id";
    $checkchange2 ="<img src='images/greencheck.jpg' title='Send Rental Agreement' border='0' height='24' width='24'></img>";
    echo $checkchange1.";".$checkchange2.";";           
}
}
}
}   
?>
```

Updated:
I downloaded the TinyMCE as suggested and made the changes below.  I have 3 remaining issues.

1 - the TinyMCE does not show any images so I need to look into that.
2 - although it allows me to edit it....none of the edits to the email or source are actually submitted on button click.
3 -  there is html code showing up at the bottom of the email that I can not see or find...so still looking into that.

I have changed my javascript to the following -

```
    $(".step5").on("click", function () {
    var element = $(this);
    var I = element.attr("id");
    var code =  $("#stepI" + I).attr("value");
    var checkname =  $("#stepI" + I).attr("title");
    $("#email").html("<h3>Loading</h3>").css("display", "block");
    $.get("emailtest1.php?code=" + code + "&id=" + I + "&checkname=" + checkname , function (data) {
        $("#email").html(data);
        $("#snd").click(function () {
            var send_to = document.getElementById("addy").value;                
            var email_body = document.getElementById("content").value;
            $("#email").append("<br /><br /><div><i>Sending...</i></div>");
            $.post("emailtest1.php?code=" + code, {
                mode: "snd", send_to: send_to, email_body: email_body          
            }, function (data) {
            var response = (data).split("z",3);         
            $("#email").html(response[0]);
            $("#stepI" + I).attr("title", (response[1]));   
            $("#stepJ" + I).html(response[2]);
            $("#stepJ" + I).hide();
            $("#stepJ" + I).fadeIn(1500);
                });                                 
        });
        $("#cnx").click(function () {
            $.post("emailtest1.php?code=" + code, {
                mode: "cnx"
            }, function (data) {
                $("#email").html(data);

            });
        });
    });
});
```

I changed my page1.php to the following

```
echo "<td>";
if ($x == "Y"){$sent1 = "Y"; $checkcolor1 = 'images/greencheck.jpg';} else {$sent1 = "N"; $checkcolor1 = 'images/redcheck.jpg';}
echo "<div id='stepI$a' title='$sent1$a' value='$mycode'><a id='$a' href='#' class ='step5'><div id='stepJ$a'><img src='$checkcolor1' title='Email Test' border='0' height='24' width='24'></img></div></a></div>";
echo "<div id='email'></div>";
```

I changed my page2.php to the following

```
function showForm(){
$id = $_GET['id'];
$checkname =$_GET['checkname'];
$rest = $checkname [0];


$mail_body =' the body of my email';}


echo '<script type="text/javascript">

tinymce.init({
selector: "textarea",
auto_focus: "elm1",
width: 1100,
height: 2500,
plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});

</script>
<h3>Email To Send</h3>
<form name="mf" id="mf" method="post" action="">
<p><label>Address :</label><input type="text" size="35" name="addy" id="addy" value="'.$e.'"/></p>
<textarea name="content" id="content" style="width:100%" value="\''.$clean_mail_body.'\'"></textarea>
<p><a href="#" class="btn" id="snd" name="snd"><img src="images/submitbutton.jpg" title="Send Email" border="0" height="25" width="75"></img></a><a href="#" class="btn" id="cnx" name="cnx">   <img src="images/cancelemail.jpg" title="Send Email" border="0" height="25" width="80"></img></a></p>
</form>';
}
}
}

function cnxForm(){
            echo '<a href=""><img src="/images/logo.png"></a><br/><h3>Email Not Sent</h3><script type="text/javascript">setTimeout(\'$("#email").fadeOut("fast")\',2000);</script>';
}

function sndForm(){

            $send_to = $_POST['send_to'];
            $email_body = $_POST['email_body'];

            $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
                       'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n" .
                       'From: Rental<test@test.com>' . "\r\n" .
                       'Reply-To: test@test.com' . "\r\n" .
                       'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();         
            $subject = 'Rental Agreement';

            mail($send_to, $subject, $email_body, $headers);                

            $checkchange0 ='<a href=""><img src="/images/logo.png"></a><br/><h3>Email Sent</h3><script type="text/javascript">setTimeout(\'$("#email").fadeOut("fast")\',2000);</script>';
            $checkchange1 ="Y$id";
            $checkchange2 ="<img src='images/greencheck.jpg' title='Send Rental Agreement' border='0' height='24' width='24'></img>";
            echo $checkchange0."z".$checkchange1."z".$checkchange2."z";

}


$mode=(!empty($_GET['mode']))?$_GET['mode']:$_POST['mode'];
switch($mode){
case 'snd': sndForm();break;
case 'cnx': cnxForm();break;
default: showForm();break;
}
}
```

Comment: You are answering your question, put in practice. The text of the email can be edited, easily but ugly with a textbox, kindof hard but prettier with a RTE editor.

Comment: Thanks for the response back. The post is actually getting created through javascript and is waiting for a response back.  I still need the response back, but only after the email is sent.

Comment: Try [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things first:

- You obviously have to change your existing code somewhere;
- Your question is very general, so my answer will be as well.

You have most of the code already, so it's not going to be a big change (I figure, I can't see your code).

How I would do it:

1. POST the values to a PHP script;
2. There generate the email (so far you are good);
3. Then, instead of sending this email (you'll have to change your code there), display it on a page to the user (emails are generally HTML, so that shouldn't be too hard) inside a rich text editor so the user can edit it. Take a pick: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2008/12/20-excellent-free-rich-text-editors/.
4. On that page with the editor, display another button and send the edited email to a PHP script that contains the code for sending the email (which you already had).

On this rich text editor: I looked briefly at TinyMCE. It converts a normal `<textarea>` to an editor, so you can just put it in a `<form action="[yourScript].php" action="POST">` and submit the edited email to the server with a `<input type="submit">`.

<s>Thanks to Mr. Polywhirl: TinyMCE isn't maintained anymore, CKEditor seems a good alternative.</s> That seems to be false. TinyMCE had a release 4 weeks ago.

**EDIT:**
I just read your comment on your own question, suggesting you post the form data to your script with an AJAX request. In that case:

1. Split your PHP code into two scripts: one that *generates* the email and one that *sends* it.
2. Post the data to the mail generator. The generator sends the mail back as response to the AJAX call.
3. Then, you have the mail client-side, display the RTE to the user (for example using something from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124561/simplest-jquery-lightbox-for-html-content))
4. and issue another AJAX call when the user submits the email, posting the mail to the script that sends mails. (Watch out people don't use it to send spam.)

Comment: I appreciate your reply.  The question was meant to be general to spark some sort of discussion on concepts since I am at a loss. I will post the code that I am using.

Comment: lol...I will look at what you wrote and let you know...was busy getting the script I am using together.  Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Where do you see that? They just had a release [two weeks ago](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=32890)?

Comment: Indeed. After I saw Mike B's comment, I checked their Github repository. It said "last updated 22 minutes ago". @Mr.Polywhirl

Comment: @11684 I downloaded the TinyMCE you suggested and have half of it done. It shows and I am able to edit the email.  Working now on the sending of it part.  Thanks for the suggestion.